# Insert / Upsert using DQL with RDF format, escaping rules for <object>

Tags: rdf, dgraph

I am trying to understand which characters need to be escaped when performing an insert or upsert using the RDF syntax on Dgraph. When looking at the following:

```
<subject> <predicate> <object> .
```

I already understood the when using `special` characters in the `<predicate>` part, (such as `//` in `http://some-uri/...`) this needs to be wrapped in `<>`. I can not easily find what the requirements for the  are though. On those objects that represent strings that are user defined I expect users to insert for instance a double-quote, but in essence any character from UTF-8. Can someone point me to the documentation where I can find the requirements for escaping the `<object>`.

Thanks in advance, Sam